# What is a neat way to apply logging without letting the loggin clutter your code?

Tags: c#, oop

At the moment I am implementing an import module. But it is also a requirement that every action must be logged. For example. When I import a customer, I need to check if that customer already exists and if the customer doesn't exists, I need to create the customer. I need to log both situations.

So at the moment I have some code like this:

```
public event Action<string> OnMessageLog;

public void ImportOrder()
{
    LogMessage("The order is being created");
    var customer = ImportCustomer("MG_001");
    var order = new Order{ Customer = customer };
    LogMessage("The order is created");

    unitOfWork.Orders.AddObject(order);
}

public Customer ImportCustomer(string customerCode)
{
    var customer = this.unitOfWork.Customers.GetByCode(customerCode);

    if(customer == null)
    {
        LogMessage("The customer doesn't exists. A new customer is created");
        customer = new Customer{ \\.. here some initialization };
    }
    else
    {
       LogMessage("The customer exists.");
    }

    return customer;
}

private void LogMessage(string message)
{
     if(OnMessageLog != null)
     {
         OnMessageLog(message);
     }
}
```

I don't really like this, because I think all the 'LogMessage(...)' calls aren't very neat.

As an alternative I was thinking about using the Decorator Pattern, but this becomes to hard to implement because the import is pretty complex. That would mean that I need to create 2 methods for each action (and I have a lot of actions)..

Do you have some suggestions or some ideas that can make this code more readable / more neat?

Comment: Check if it may works for your scenario and then (it's kind of typical example of) AOP, AOP, AOP, AOP...

Answer (score 5):

You could try aspect oriented programming by using a tool like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/).

Comment: With Roslyn that may become easier, but the idea is the same. To some extent IOCs supporting the interception allow to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but how to deal with conditions inside a method? For example my 'ImportCustomer' method. It logs two different situations.

Comment: Have a look at: http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator and the section about the "OnEntry"-method. It lets you capture (among other things) the arguments sent into the function. It may be that you have to restructure some of your code in order to log exactly what you want. For example handling new and existing customers in two different methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think Decorator is a way to go. Extracting GetCustomerByCode and CreateCustomer methods is a good idea even if you don't need any logging. May be some of these methods will be reused across your module, may be they don't. It still makes code more readable, testable and maintainable.

```
public Customer ImportCustomer(string customerCode)
{
    var customer = GetCustomerByCode(string customerCode);

    if (customer == null)
    {
        customer = CreateCustomer();
    }

    return customer;
}

public Customer GetCustomerByCode(string customerCode)
{
    var customer = this.unitOfWork.Customers.GetByCode(customerCode);

    return customer;
}

public Customer CreateCustomer()
{
    var customer = new Customer{ \\.. here some initialization };

    return customer;
}
```